# Which phrase is right?

Tags: grammar

While speaking, when they want to highlight some difference, people often do it by stating where they come from.

Which of these phrases is correct:

1. From where I come from
   Or
2. Where I come from

I guess the second one is correct but I have also heard the first phrase too. That's why I am confused.

Comment: I think the first is conflating "From where I'm standing" and "Where I come from".

Answer (score 1):

The second is correct. I've never heard the first one said, but I can imagine it being used in error by someone who is not a native English speaker.

The context of the second phrase could be something like 'Where I come from people like to have a sleep in the afternoon and this is called a siesta.'

If you were to try using the second phrase in this way it would sound like 'From where I come from people like to have a sleep in the afternoon and this is called a siesta.' This just sounds imcorrect to me. Either of the instances of 'from' needs removing for it to sound correct.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Both phrases are correct, but from a writing point of view, your choice between them should be governed by the personality of the character who is speaking.

The first option is more formal and would be used by a character with a professional bearing or a character in a servile role.  The second is more relaxed and colloquial, reflecting a character who is either confident enough to speak plainly, or too dim to speak otherwise.

Comment: So there is no grammatical error in either of them? And we can use 'from' two times in a phrase?

Comment: @user81329 The first is actually more dubious than the second, and would not be accepted in formal writing—for the very reason that it does use *from* twice. Either *From where do I come?* or *Where do I come from?* would be fine. But more context would be needed to know if these are meant to be questions or parts of larger sentences. As statements, exactly as written, neither seems quite right. (Then again, people *speak* much differently than they write.) More context is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Both phrases are 'correct'.

**come from** the idiom [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Come+from), can have a unique meaning:

> 4. To have an **attitude or opinion** because of some situation; To have a particular perspective or attitude regarding a person or situation

This idiom typicically starts a statement, and thus prepares one to hear an attitude or strong opinion.  You never actually hear where he/she  came from, but wherever it is, *truth and fact* originated! Most other uses of **come from** are benign and self explanatory.